# Angular unit test works in browser but errors in Chutzpah

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, qunit, chutzpah

I have an angular module which uses the angular ui bootstrap typeahead directive. I am attempting to unit test this with qunit and chutzpah.

The unit test runs and passes when run through a browser, but returns an error when run with Chutzpah:

> Error: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp
>   due to: Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available! You
>   either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering
>   a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second
>   argument.

Why is this error occurring?

**JS**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.factory('myFactory', ['$http', function ($http) {
        var myFactory = {};
        myFactory.getLocations = function (query) {
            return $http.get('/Locations', { params: { query: query } });
        };

        return myFactory;
    }]);

    app.controller('MyController', ['myFactory', function (myFactory) {
        this.location = '';

        this.getLocations = function (query) {
            return myFactory.getLocations(query).then(function (response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        };
    }]);
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="MyController as my">
    <input name="location" type="text" data-ng-model="my.location" data-typeahead="location for location in my.getLocations($viewValue)" class="form-control">
</div>
```

**Unit Test**

```
///<reference path="angular.js"/>
///<reference path="angular-mocks.js"/>
///<reference path="angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"/>
///<reference path="qunit-1.15.0.js"/>
///<reference path="sinon-1.9.1.js"/>
///<reference path="myapp.js"/>

var appMocks = angular.module("appMocks", []);

appMocks.config(function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$httpBackend', angular.mock.e2e.$httpBackendDecorator);
});

var injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'myApp', 'appMocks']);
var scope = {};
var $controllers = injector.get('$controller');
var $httpBackend = injector.get('$httpBackend');
var myFactory = injector.get('myFactory');

QUnit.module("MyApp Tests", {
    setup: function () {
        scope = injector.get('$rootScope').$new();
        $controllers('MyController as my', {
            $scope: scope,
            myFactory: myFactory
        });
    }
});

QUnit.test('Get locations returns valid locations', function (assert) {
    $httpBackend.expectGET('/Locations?query=l').respond(['london', 'leeds']);

    var result;
    scope.my.getLocations('l').then(function (response) {
        result = response;
    });
    $httpBackend.flush();

    assert.equal(2, result.length, "correct number of results returned");
});
```

**Chutzpah Settings**

```
{    
    "Framework": "qunit",
    "CodeCoverageIncludes": ["*.js"],
    "CodeCoverageExcludes": [
        "*\\sinon-1.9.1.js",  
        "*\\angular.js", 
        "*\\angular-mocks.js",
        "*\\angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
        "*\\Tests\\*"
    ],   
    "RootReferencePathMode":"SettingsFileDirectory",
    "TestHarnessDirectory": "./"
}
```

Comment: My guess would be (based on the error message) that it is unable to load the `myapp.js` file. Unfortunately, I don't know Chutzpah. :/ I would look at what files are actually loaded, and how.

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could upload a repro to github and share the repo.

Comment: @MatthewManela Thanks, I've uploaded a repro to github - https://github.com/ChaoticNadirs/ChutzpahTestFailure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is one of .js loading order. When you are running with code coverage the blanket.js plugin will instrument your files and cause them to load asynchronously. Since you were excluding your test files from instrumentation it was loading it before the source file. To change this just allow your test file to be instrumented by removing "*\test-js\*"  from your coverageexcludes section:

```
{    
    "Framework": "qunit",
    "CodeCoverageIncludes": ["*.js"],
    "CodeCoverageExcludes": [
        "*\\angular/angular.js", 
        "*\\angular/angular-mocks.js",
        "*\\angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js",
        "*\\qunit/qunit-1.15.0.js",
        "*\\sinon/sinon-1.9.1.js"
    ],   
    "RootReferencePathMode":"SettingsFileDirectory",
    "TestHarnessDirectory": "./"
}
```